# how to connect vb.net thorgh online phpmyadmin

Tags: vb.net

Dim conn As MysqlConnection

```
conn = New Mysqlconnection()
conn.ConnectionString = "server=justhost.com; user id=*****; password=****; database=login"

Try
    conn.Open()
Catch myerror As MySqlException
    MsgBox("Error connecting to database!")
End Try
```

this  code not working ? how to connect online phpmyadmin database use vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing this one?

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

and after installing that, try to reconfigure your code try this.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Dim Connection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection()
Dim ConnectionString As String = "Server=SERVERNAME or the Database online link;Database=DATABASE;Uid=root;Pwd=password;"
Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
Connection.Open()

//Execute here what ever you want just follow your heart <3

myConnection.Close()
```